# Evaluate an infinite sum using Fourier series

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Using,
$f(t) =
\begin{cases}
\pi^2  & -\pi<t<0 \\[2ex]
(t-\pi)^2 & 0<t<\pi
\end{cases}$

The value of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$ needs to be determined.

I found the Fourier series as $$f(x)=\frac{2\pi^2}{3}+\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{2}{i^2}\cos(ix)+\sum_{i=1}^n b_i\sin(ix)$$

I tried setting the values $x=\pm\pi$, only to get different (also incorrect) answers in both cases.

Any help is appreciated.

Note: $b_i$ left out as it seemed irrelevant for the purposes of the question. Please let me know if it is otherwise.

Comment: Are you sure that your Fourier series is correct?

Comment: Do you know that when you plug $\pm \pi$ into the Fourier series of $f$, you get the average of the left-hand limit and the right-hand limit, so $\frac{\pi^2}{2}$?

Answer (score 1):

One can just use $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2} x^2 (-\pi<x \leq \pi).$$
Then, the Fourier series will be $$f(x)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}+2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k^2} \cos(kx).$$ When $x=0$, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{12}.$$